# Parallel execution of callables

Tags: java, multithreading, callable

I'd like to execute multiple callables parallel. But it seems that the ExecutorService always waits until all callables are finnished.

I've tried the following:

```
final int nThreads = 10;
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads);
List<PrimeCallable> tasks = new ArrayList<PrimeCallable>();
for(int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++) {
    tasks.add(new PrimeCallable(0, i * 100 + 100, "thread" + i));
}

try {
    for(Future<List<Integer>> result : executorService.invokeAll(tasks)) {
        List<Integer> integers = result.get();
        for(Integer i : integers){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now, the for loop is called when all callables in the executorService are finnished. As far as I know, there is no executorService.isParallel setter ;-).

What would be the right approach to let callables run parallel?

Thanks for your hints!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The javadocs for [invokeAll](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll%28java.util.Collection%29) says;

> Executes the given tasks, returning a
>   list of Futures holding their status
>   and results **when all complete**. Future.isDone() is true for each element of the returned list.

So `invokeAll` blocks until each task in the collection is complete.

Comment: So what should we use if we just want to start our List<Callables> and not wait for all of them to complete!

Answer (score 7):

Executor service runs all your callables in parallel. All it does is , it waits for all parallel tasks to complete before it moves on. So its not like where all the tasks are run in serial.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like part of what you want is *lazy* execution - you don't want to have to make a copy of the structure in memory before extracting results.

I would treat this as an iteration + transformation problem.  First, define an iterator over your input, such that each call to next() returns a Callable that will produce the next value in your series.

The transform stage is to apply a parallel or concurrent evaluation of those Callables, something like this (not tested):

```
public class ConcurrentTransform
{
  private final ExecutorService executor;
  private final int maxBuffer;

  public ConcurrentTransform(ExecutorService executor, int maxWorkBuffer) {
    this.executor = executor;
    this.maxBuffer = Math.max(1, maxWorkBuffer);
  }

  public <T> Iterator<T> apply(final Iterator<Callable<T>> input) {
    // track submitted work
    final BlockingQueue<Future<T>> submitted = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Future<T>>();

    // submit first N tasks
    for (int i=0; i<maxBuffer && input.hasNext(); i++) {
      Callable<T> task = input.next();
      Future<T> future = executor.submit(task);
      submitted.add(future);
    }

    return new Iterator<T>(){
      @Override
      public synchronized boolean hasNext() {
        return !submitted.isEmpty();
      }
      @Override
      public T next() {
        Future<T> result;
        synchronized (this) {
          result = submitted.poll();
          if (input.hasNext()) {
            submitted.add(executor.submit(input.next()));
          }
        }

        if (result != null) {
          try {
            return result.get(); // blocking
          } catch (Exception e) {
            if (e instanceof RuntimeException) {
               throw (RuntimeException) e;
            } else {
               throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
          }
        } else {
          throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
      }
      @Override
      public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
      }};
  }
}
```

After calling apply(...), you'd iterate over the resulting values, which under the covers would be executing the Callable objects in parallel and returning results in the same order as they were input. Some refinements would be to allow an optional timeout for the blocking result.get() call, or to manage the thread pool within the transform itself.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to view results as they happen, use the `ExecutorCompletionService`.